# Machine epsilon vs least positive number

Tags: floating-point

What is the difference between machine epsilon and least positive number in floating point representation?

If I try to show the floating point number on a number line .Is the gap between exact 0 and the first positive (number which floating point can represent) ,and the gap between two successive numbers, different?

which one is generally  smaller?
and on which factor these two values depends(mantisa or exponent)?

Answer (score 3):

[*Machine epsilon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) is the *relative* error (the error independent of what exponent you are currently using.)

It tells you the maximum error in the *mantissa* after a given operation.  For example take `sqrt(2.0)` and `sqrt(2048.0) = sqrt(2.0)*32.0`.  In IEEE 754 double precision (53-bit mantissa) the maximum error in the mantissa for this result will be $2^{-53} \approx 1.11\times10^{-16}$.

Put another way, to [quote Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Formal_definition), the machine epsilon is

> the maximum spacing between a normalised floating point number, $x$, and an adjacent normalised number is $2 \epsilon \times |x|$.

The *least positive number* in a floating point system *includes the exponent*.  In double precision IEEE 754 the smallest *normalized* number is $2^{-1022} \approx 2.225 \times 10^{-308}$.  The smallest *denormalized* number is $2^{-52}\times 2^{-1022}=2^{-1074}\approx 4.941\times 10^{-324}$.